# Find the range of $\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find the range of $\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}$

**My Attempt:**$$y^2=\frac{x^2+2x-3}{x^2+4x+4}=z\\\implies  x^2(z-1)+x(4z-2)+4z+3=0$$

Discriminant greater than equal to zero, so, $$(4z-2)^2-4(z-1)(4z+3)\ge0\\\implies z\le\frac43\\\implies -\frac2{\sqrt3}\le y\le\frac2{\sqrt3}$$

But the answer given is $[-\frac2{\sqrt3},1]$

What am I missing?

Comment: $\frac {-x + 3x}{2x} = x = \sqrt x$. Range is a derivative of two scalar quantities. They are the limit

Comment: Yeah, $y$ must lie in the interval $\left[-\frac2{\sqrt3},\frac2{\sqrt3}\right]$ but in order to conclude that this interval is indeed the range of function $f$, where $f:\Bbb{R} \setminus \{-2\} \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}$, you have to ensure that every point in the interval $\left[-\frac2{\sqrt3},\frac2{\sqrt3}\right]$ has a pre-image in $f$, i.e., $\forall y \in \left[-\frac2{\sqrt3},\frac2{\sqrt3}\right] \exists x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \{-2\}$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: When you square both sides of an equation, you can get some extraneous solutions which you have to eliminate before concluding that the obtained set of solutions is the same set of solutions desired for the original equation.

Comment: 1 does not belong to the range!

Comment: @Darweesh, it does.

Comment: @aarbee 1 is not in the range. There are no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @FinnT, how about $x=-\frac72$?

Comment: @aarbee if $x=-7/2$ so $\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}=-1$. In fact, you can show that $\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}=1$ has not solution.  So $1$ is not range, I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: @user1027216 thanks

Comment: @FinnT thankyou

Comment: @Darweesh thanks

Comment: @aarbee If you agree with any of the responses provided by MSE users, it is a good practice to value your effort in responding, accepting their responses by double-checking the green color on the response that is most appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that squaring an equation may introduce [extraneous solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions). You either have to check each solution (by substituting it into the original equation), or you use equivalent equations throughout the solution process which ensures extraneous solutions won't occur. Taking the second approach, your equation $y=\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}/(x+2)$ is equivalent to the system
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(y^2-1)x^2+2(2y^2-1)x+4y^2+3=0\\
y(x+2)\ge 0\\
x+2\ne 0
\end{array}
\right. $$
The range of $f$ is those $y$ for which the system has a solution. For $y^2-1=0\Leftrightarrow y=\pm1$, the equation is $2x+7=0\Leftrightarrow x=-7/2$. With $y=1$ the first inequality isn't satisfied while $y=-1$ is ok. So $y=-1$ is in the range of $f$ and $y=1$ isn't. For $y^2-1\ne 0$, the quadratic formula gives
$$x=\frac{1-2y^2\pm\sqrt{4-3y^2}}{y^2-1},\quad\quad
y\in\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt 3},\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\right]\setminus\{-1,1\} $$
and now you have to solve the inequalities $y(x+2)\ge 0,x+2\ne 0$ with each of the two roots for $x$. That is, you have to solve
$$\frac{y\left(-1-\sqrt{4-3y^2}\right)}{y^2-1}\ge0\\-1-\sqrt{4-3y^2}\ne 0 $$
and
$$\frac{y\left(-1+\sqrt{4-3y^2}\right)}{y^2-1}\ge0\\-1+\sqrt{4-3y^2}\ne 0 $$
The solutions to these are, respectively, $y\in\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},-1\right)\cup\left[0,1\right)$ and $y\in\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},-1\right)\cup\left(-1,0\right]$. Combining the two sets and also adding $y=-1$ (but not $y=1$), we conclude that the range of $f$ is
$$\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},1\right)$$

**Edit:** For the second pair of inequalities, you can use
$$-1+\sqrt{4-3y^2}
=\frac{\left(-1+\sqrt{4-3y^2}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{4-3y^2}\right)}{1+\sqrt{4-3y^2}}
=\frac{-3(y^2-1)}{1+\sqrt{4-3y^2}} $$

Comment: For the inequality $$\frac{y(-1-\sqrt{4-3y^2})}{y^2-1}\ge0,$$ $-1-\sqrt{4-3y^2}$ is always negative. So, $y\in[\frac{-2}{\sqrt3},-1)\cup[0,1)$. But how do we solve $$\frac{y(-1+\sqrt{4-3y^2})}{y^2-1}\ge0$$

Comment: @aarbee Right. For the second pair of inequalities, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

First notice that
$${\rm Dom}(f)=\left]-\infty,-3\right]\cup \left[1,+\infty\right[$$
Now, setting
$$y=f(x)\implies y=\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}\implies y^{2}=\frac{(x-1)(x+3)}{(x+2)^{2}}$$
Then,
$$y^{2}(x+2)^{2}=(x-1)(x+3)$$
Expanding and collecting all in terms of $x$, we have
$$(1-y^{2})x^{2}+(2-4y^{2})x+(-3-4y^{2})=0,\quad (*)$$
Using the quadratic formula we get
$$x=\frac{1-2y^{2}\pm \sqrt{4-3y^{2}}}{y^{2}-1},\quad (**)$$
Then,

- If $y=-1$, then $x=-\frac{7}{2}\in {\rm Dom}(f)$ using $(*)$ so not problem.
- If $y\not=\pm 1$ so only we need $4-3y^{2}\geqslant 0$ so $-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\leqslant y\leqslant \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. $[◇]$

Joint all, we have

$${\rm range}(f)=\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},1\right[$$
as desired.

**Fixed and more details:**

Notice with $y=1$, we have $1=\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+3)}}{x+2}$  which don't have solutions over $\mathbb{R}$. Then exclude the $1$ of the interval.

Well, by $(**)$ we get
$$y\in \left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},-1\right[\cup \left]-1,1\right[\cup \left]-1,\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right[$$
then we have the conclusion give in $[◇]$. However the interval $\left]-1,\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right[$ is a strange solution (just study $f$ using the domain and the conclusion as follows), so we remove it. In my previous post I included the value $1$ in the range, however it was a mistake because as said above. Therefore the range of $f$ over the natural domain is given by
$${\rm range}(f)=\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},-1\right[\cup \left]-1,1\right[=\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},1\right[.$$

Comment: Your answer makes it clear why $-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \leq y \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.  It is not clear how you concluded that the range is actually $\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, 1\right]$.

Comment: Well, if $y=1$ so we don't have solutions for $x$ so the correct interval should be $[-2/\sqrt{3},1[$, I corrected. By other hand, when I wrote "joint all" I was saying that using the fact domain of $f$ and the intervals obtained we have the conclusion. I don't understand what's part is not clear. I can add more details if you like, no problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I fixed the mistake excluding $1$ as indicated above. Also, I added the argument which I followed to give the conclusion I had given before. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: You meant to write $]1, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}[$ rather than $]-1, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}[$.  After doing some algebra, I came to the conclusion that $y > 1$ leads to a contradiction, so your argument is now correct except for the aforementioned typographical error.  I did not figure out what you meant by your parenthetical remark "just study $f$ using the domain and the conclusion follows" until I tried solving the inequality $y > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is that $|y| \leq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.  While that does imply that $-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \leq y \leq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, you cannot necessarily conclude that the range is $\left[-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$ since you obtained that result by squaring both sides of the equation, which is not a reversible step.

We are given the function
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \frac{\sqrt{(x + 3)(x - 1)}}{x + 2}\\
     & = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}{x + 2}
\end{align*}
Observe that its domain of the function $f$ is $(-\infty, -3] \cup [1, \infty)$.

Differentiating gives
\begin{align*}
f'(x) & = \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}(2x + 2)(x + 2) - \sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}{(x + 2)^2}\\
      & = \frac{\frac{(x + 1)(x + 2)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}} - \sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}{(x + 2)^2}\\
      & = \frac{\frac{x^2 + 3x + 2 - (x^2 + 2x - 3)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}}{(x + 2)^2}\\
      & = \frac{x + 5}{(x + 2)^2\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}
\end{align*}
Setting the derivative equal to zero yields
\begin{align*}
f'(x) & = 0\\
\frac{x + 5}{(x + 2)^2\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}} & = 0\\
x + 5 & = 0\\
x & = -5
\end{align*}
Thus, the function has a critical point at $x = -5$.

Observe that the denominator of the derivative function is always positive within the domain of the function. Therefore, the sign of the derivative depends only on the numerator.  Hence, $f'(x) < 0$ if $x < -5$, $f'(-5) = 0$, and $f'(x) > 0$ if $-5 < x < -3$.  Since the sign of the derivative changes from negative to positive at the critical point $x = -5$, the function has a relative minimum at $x = -5$ by the [First Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#First-derivative_test).

Its relative minimum value is
\begin{align*}
f(-5) & = \frac{\sqrt{(-5)^2 + 2(-5) - 3}}{-5 + 2}\\
      & = \frac{\sqrt{25 - 10 - 3}}{-3}\\
      & = \frac{\sqrt{12}}{-3}\\
      & = \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{-3}\\
      & = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}

Also, note that $f'(x) > 0$ when $x > 1$.  Therefore, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on the interval $[1, \infty)$.  Observe that $f(1) = 0$.  Moreover,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) & = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}{x + 2}\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{|x|\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2}}}{x\left(1 + \frac{2}{x}\right)}\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2}}}{x\left(1 + \frac{2}{x}\right)}\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1  + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2}}}{1 + \frac{2}{x}}\\
& = 1 
\end{align*}
Since the function $f$ is continuous on the interval $[1, \infty)$, it assumes every value in the interval $[0, 1)$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Observe that $f(-3) = 0$.  Since $f$ assumes the value $-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ at $x = -5$ and is continuous on the interval $[-5, 0]$, it assumes every value in the interval $\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, 0\right]$ in the interval $[-5, 0]$.  Moreover,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) & = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x - 3}}{x + 2}\\
& = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{|x|\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2}}}{x\left(1 + \frac{2}{x}\right)}\\
& = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-x\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2}}}{x\left(1 + \frac{2}{x}\right)}\\
& = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-\sqrt{1  + \frac{2}{x} - \frac{3}{x^2}}}{1 + \frac{2}{x}}\\
& = -1 
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is continuous on the interval $(-\infty, -5]$, it assumes every value in the interval $\left[-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, -1\right)$ in the interval $(-\infty, -5]$.

Therefore, the range of $f$ is
$$\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, -1\right) \cup \left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, 0\right] \cup [0, 1) = \left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, 1\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. I have accepted the other answer but I have learnt a lot from your answer too. Thanks.

Comment: When we got derivative zero at $x=-5$, you have written relative minimum value at $x=-5$. Can't we say, at that time itself, that the global minimum will be at $x=-5$?. Also, after getting this minimum value, can we just check the values at ± infinity and the bigger value will be the maximum value? Or that doesn't ensure the continuity of the range?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

A little bit different approach from the other users.

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{(x - 1)(x + 3)}}{x + 2} & = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + 2x - 3}}{x + 2}\\\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{(x^{2} + 4x + 4) - (2x + 4) - 3}}{x + 2}\\\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{(x + 2)^{2} - 2(x + 2) - 3}}{x + 2}\\\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{[(x + 2) - 1]^{2} - 4}}{x + 2}\\\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{(x + 1)^{2} - 4}}{(x + 1) + 1}
\end{align*}

Now we can make the change of variable $u = x + 1$ and study the range of the transformed expression:
\begin{align*}
y = \frac{\sqrt{u^{2} - 4}}{u + 1} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
y(u + 1) = \sqrt{u^{2} - 4}\\\\
|u| \geq 2
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(1 - y^{2})u^{2} - 2y^{2}u - y^{2} - 4 = 0\\\\
|u| \geq 2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi. I think the equation is $(1-y^2)u^2-2y^2u-y^2-4=0?$

Comment: @aarbee Indeed, thanks for the comment. I have fixed it.

Comment: Isn't the coefficient of $u$, $-2y^2$ instead of $-2y$?

Comment: @aarbee Once again, thank you for pointing it out.